# Not waiting at await call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mahapps.metro

I am using [SimpleChildWindow](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow). The [usage guide](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow) has example on how to use. I used this as the guide:

```
private async void OpenAChildWindow_OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // opens a cool child window
  await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(new CoolChildWindow() { IsModal = false });
}
```

I am making the call in my button click even handler as below:

```
private async void OnChildWindowClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(new SimpleChildWindowImplementation() { IsModal = false, AllowMove = true, Title = "This is title" });
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

What I see is that the await waits correctly for 10 secs. However the second await does not wait at all. And then the console also shows the debug "Hello". When I come out of the click handler method, the child window is shown.

Why does it not show the child window first and then the debug "Hello" message?

The SimpleChildWindowImplementation right now is exactly same as the CoolChildWindow in the sample provided. The idea is to change it later to suit my needs.

**EDIT:**

I changed [ChildWindowManager.cs](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow/blob/master/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow/ChildWindowManager.cs) and tweaked the implementation of ShowChildWindowInternalAsync function as below to make it working.

```
private static Task<string> ShowChildWindowInternalAsync(ChildWindow dialog, Panel container)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    var firstTask = Task.Factory
               .StartNew(() => dialog.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => container.Children.Add(dialog))));

    var continuationTask = firstTask.ContinueWith(_ => dialog.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Func<Task>(() =>
               {
                   RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
                   handler = (sender, args) =>
                   {
                       dialog.ClosingFinished -= handler;
                       container.Children.Remove(dialog);
                       tcs.TrySetResult("done");
                   };
                   dialog.ClosingFinished += handler;
                   dialog.IsOpen = true;
                   return tcs.Task;
               })));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Not marking it as answer. Will await feedback from @punker76.

Comment: Put another await delay before Console.Writeline to make sure its not just unexpected timing. Also, just because it is awaitable  doesn't mean it was implemented as you expect.

Comment: @Crowcoder You can just create your own workaround with the ClosingFinished event until I add the Task result in 1.0

Comment: @Crowcoder: Sorry for delay in reply. Adding another await delay indeed led to the child window getting displayed first and then the Console.WriteLine. And it is timing dependent. On very small time duration it still behaves like before.

Comment: In case you really want to observe on the actual appearance, you can wait on the storyboard of "show" or "hide", which has [Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.aspx#events) event.

Comment: @punker76 What you think of the code change? Will it break anything?

Comment: Well, there is still no task result in version 1.3 of SimpleChildWindow - problem still exists...

Answer (score 2):

I have just looked into the source code.

Basically, `ShowChildWindowAsync` sets `ChildWindow`'s `IsOpen` to `true`. This triggers `IsOpenedChanged`, and it eventually calls

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(childWindow, (bool)e.NewValue == false ? "Hide" : "Show", true);
```

Both the change on `IsOpen` and [`GoToState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx) return immediately, and the actual result (the appearance of the window) takes effect later asynchronously.